# Java swing simple address book event error

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm trying to make a simple address book GUI that will eventually be able to add all fields like name number to a database. At the moment I'm trying to add methods to change what will happen when a button is pushed but I keep getting this errors ...

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at AddressBook.actionPerformed(AddressBook.java:122)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
.
.
. theres some more but you get the point
```

I was wondering if anyone could help me find out why I keep getting this error or even anyway to improve the structure of this program. Thanks!

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.border.EtchedBorder;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class AddressBook implements ActionListener{

    JFrame frame;
    JPanel Master, centerInfo, buttonInfo;
    GridBagConstraints constraints;
    GridBagConstraints topconstraint;
    JLabel jlb_firstName, jlb_lastName, jlb_phoneNum, jlb_searchInfo;
    JTextField jtf_firstName, jtf_lastName, jtf_phoneNum;
    JTextArea jta_searchInfo;
    JButton jb_add, jb_search, jb_share;
    Container pane;

    String firstName, lastName, phoneNum;

    //address book designed in GridBagLayout via swing
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        AddressBook a = new AddressBook();
        System.out.println("hello world");
        a.start_gui();
    }


    public void start_gui()
    {   
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Address Book");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Container pane = new Container();
        pane = frame.getContentPane();
        layComponents(pane);
        //frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setSize(400,400);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    private void layComponents(Container contentPane)
    {
        //PANELS,CONTENTPANE,CONSTRAINTS
        JPanel Master = new JPanel();
        JPanel centerInfo = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        JPanel buttonInfo = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING,10,5));
        Master.add(centerInfo, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        Master.add(buttonInfo, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        contentPane.add(Master);                        //set style of layout for GUI
        GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();      //layout constraints
        GridBagConstraints topconstraint = new GridBagConstraints();    //constraint against top of GUI

        constraints.insets = new Insets(5,5,10,10);
        //components: firstName, lastName, phoneNum, info, Add, Search(need to add oracle sql db)

        //LABELS
        JLabel jlb_firstName = new JLabel("First Name");
        topconstraint.gridx =1;
        topconstraint.gridy =0;
        topconstraint.insets = new Insets(20,5,10,10);                  //Insets(top,left,right,down)
        centerInfo.add(jlb_firstName, topconstraint);
        JLabel jlb_lastName = new JLabel("Last Name");
        constraints.gridx =1;
        constraints.gridy =2;
        centerInfo.add(jlb_lastName,constraints);
        JLabel jlb_phoneNum = new JLabel("Phone Number");
        constraints.gridx =1;
        constraints.gridy =4;
        centerInfo.add(jlb_phoneNum,constraints);
        JLabel jlb_searchInfo = new JLabel("Search Info");
        constraints.gridx =1;
        constraints.gridy =6;
        centerInfo.add(jlb_searchInfo, constraints);

        //TEXTFIELDS
        JTextField jtf_firstName = new JTextField("Enter New First Name");      //to clear textfield when clicked need actionlisteners
        topconstraint.gridx =3;
        topconstraint.gridy =0;
        centerInfo.add(jtf_firstName,topconstraint);
        JTextField jtf_lastName = new JTextField("Enter New Last Name");
        constraints.gridx =3;
        constraints.gridy =2;
        centerInfo.add(jtf_lastName, constraints);
        JTextField jtf_phoneNum = new JTextField("Enter New Phone Number");
        constraints.gridx =3;
        constraints.gridy =4;
        centerInfo.add(jtf_phoneNum, constraints);

        //TEXTAREA
        Border loweredetched;
        loweredetched = BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.LOWERED);
        JTextArea jta_searchInfo = new JTextArea(10,20);
        jta_searchInfo.append("click me");
        jta_searchInfo.selectAll();
        jta_searchInfo.requestFocus();
        jta_searchInfo.setBorder(loweredetched);
        constraints.gridx =3;
        constraints.gridy =6;
        centerInfo.add(jta_searchInfo, constraints);

        //buttons will use flowlayout
        //BUTTONS
        JButton jb_add = new JButton("Add");
        buttonInfo.add(jb_add);
        JButton jb_search = new JButton("Search");
        buttonInfo.add(jb_search);
        JButton jb_share = new JButton("Share");
        buttonInfo.add(jb_share);   //share info with ppl. need a new share gui

        //Listen for any component actions performed
        jb_add.addActionListener(this);
        //jb_search.addActionListener(this);
        //jb_share.addActionListener(this); 
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        firstName = jtf_firstName.getText();
        System.out.println(firstName);
    }


}
```

Comment: You really need to learn to debug you code, try placing breakpoints within your code at points where the objects are initialised and used and comparing the differences and slow narrow the search by either stepping through the code or adding new break points

Comment: On line 122 of that code, you're calling a method on an object that is null. (The top line of the error message says `java.lang.NullPointerException`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've shadowed your instance variables...

You've declared...

```
JTextField jtf_firstName, jtf_lastName, jtf_phoneNum;
```

As instance fields, but in `layComponents`, you've redeclared them

```
JTextField jtf_firstName = new JTextField("Enter New First Name");
```

This means that the instance fields are `null`.

Comment: sugoi! thx man I didn't think about the design beforehand so when I decided to make the components global I left the previous initializations there derp :P